# Curl does not have time to work out when you run through Cron

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, cron

I have a PHP cron-script

```
Class Cron {
  public function __construct {
    $this->dosomething(); 
  } 
  private function dosomething () {
    $curl = app_curl(); 
  } 
} 

function app_curl () {
  ... $ Curl ... 
  return $ curl; 
}
```

When I run this script - it is not satisfied, and aborts the Cron. If I run separately app_curl (), then everything works correctly.

// fullcode

// cli/auto cron file (code igniter)

```
class Auto extends CLI_Controller {
  public function index() {
    $this->process_broadcasts();
  } // function

  private function process_broadcasts(){
    $curl = app_curl_get_postmaster();
  } // function
} // class
```

// curl_function

```
function get_web_page($url, $post = array())
{
  if (!isset($url) || empty($url)) return false;
  $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";

  $ch = curl_init( $url );

  $path = dirname(__FILE__);
  $tmpfile = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cookie' . '.txt';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     // возвращает веб-страницу

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);             // не возвращает заголовки
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");          // обрабатывает все кодировки
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);    // useragent

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);   // таймаут соединения
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);          // таймаут ответа

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);     // переходит по редиректам
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     // переходит по редиректам
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);         // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  $tmpfile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfile);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  if (isset($post) && !empty($post)) {
    if (!is_array($post)) $post[$$post] = $post;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
  }

  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
}
```

// get_postmaster

```
function app_curl_get_postmaster($date = null) {
  if ($date === null) $date = date('d.m');

  $post = array(
    'Login' => 'gzhegow2@mail.ru',
    'Domain' => 'mail.ru',
    'Password' => '321qwe',
    'saveauth' => 1,
    'new_auth_form' => 1,
    'page' => 'https://postmaster.mail.ru/',
    'post' => '',
    'login_form' => ''
  );

  $v = get_web_page('https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth', $post);
  $v = get_web_page('https://postmaster.mail.ru/100tr.ru/');

  $html = str_get_html($v['content']);

  $tmp = array();
  $arr = array();

  $tr_counter = 0;
  foreach ($html->find('table[id=stats] tr') as $tr) {
    foreach ($tr->find('td[class*=statistic-table__date]') as $td) {
      $tmp[$tr_counter]['date'] = trim($td->plaintext);
    }
    foreach ($tr->find('td[class*=statusbar__delivered]') as $td) {
      $tmp[$tr_counter]['good'] = trim($td->plaintext);
    }
    foreach ($tr->find('td[class*=statusbar__probspam]') as $td) {
      $tmp[$tr_counter]['warn'] = trim($td->plaintext);
    }
    foreach ($tr->find('td[class*=statusbar__spam]') as $td) {
      $tmp[$tr_counter]['spam'] = trim($td->plaintext);
    }
    $tr_counter++;
  };

  foreach ($tmp as $item) {
    if (isset($item['date']) && !empty($item['date'])) $arr[$item['date']] = $item;
  }

  return $arr[$date];
}
```

I think Curl has no time to execute when its run through another script, but if I do

```
print_r(app_curl_get_postmaster());
```

then everything works fine. What could be the reason?

Comment: [maybe this...?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) zero is infinite, skim the comments, too..

Comment: Are you including/requiring files, if so you may need to use full server path to file

Comment: maybe, i will test it now... more variants?

Comment: johnny, yes, function_exists returns true

Comment: my skype is gzhegow, i can display my screen

Comment: no, set_time_limit(30) not working, script always ends before the curl ends.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, i use ::

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

they tell me 'str_get_html' is 'unknown function'.
I did require simple_html_dom.php and it works.

Thanks for all, guys, for the help!